# When exporting from the database, an empty csv file is created

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql

```
public interface Client {

    Long getId();
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    LocalDate getCreated_dt();
    String getUsername();
    String getName();
    int getAmount();
    String getStatus();
    String getAccount();
    String getExternal_id();
    String getExternal_status();
}
```

DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

public class ClientDto {
    private Long id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate created_dt;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    private String status;
    private String account;
    private String external_id;
    private String external_status;

    public ClientDto(Client client) {
        this.id = client.getId();
        /...
        /...
        this.external_status = client.getExternal_status();
    }

    public ClientDto(ClientDto clientDto) {
        this.id = clientDto.getId();
        
        /...

        this.external_status = clientDto.getExternal_status();
    }

    public ClientDto(ClientEntity clientEntity) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + id + "|" + created_dt + "|" + username + "|" + name +
                "|" + amount + "|" + status + "|" + account + "|" + external_id + "|" + external_status;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments", schema = "public")
public class ClientEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_dt")
    private LocalDate created_dt;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "account")
    private String account;

    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private String external_id;

    @Column(name = "external_status")
    private String external_status;
}
```

Repository

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientEntity, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT pp.id, TO_CHAR(pp.created_dt::date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')\n" +
               "AS 'Data', CAST(pp.created_dt AS time(0)) AS 'Time', au.username AS 'UserName',\n" +
               "ss.name AS 'Service', pp.amount AS 'Amount',\n" +
               "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success') AS 'Payment_status', pp.account AS 'Account',\n" +
               "pp.external_id AS 'Idn', COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'DN')\n" +
               "AS 'Stat'\n" +
               "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
               "INNER JOIN user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
               "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
               "WHERE pp.created_dt >= '2021-09-28'\n" +
               "AND ss.name = 'Faberlic' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Client> getAllByRegDate();
}
```

Service

```
@Service
public class ClientServiceImpl implements ClientService {

   
    private final ClientRepository clientRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ClientServiceImpl(ClientRepository clientRepository) {
        this.clientRepository = clientRepository;
        JaroWinklerDistance jaroWinklerDistance = new JaroWinklerDistance();
    }

    @Override
    public List<ClientDto> getAll() {
        return clientRepository.findAll()
                .stream()
                .map(ClientDto::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Page<ClientEntity> getAll(Pageable paging) {
        return clientRepository.findAll(paging);
    }

    @Override
    public List<ClientDto> getAllByRegDateAfter() {
        return clientRepository.getAllByRegDate()
                .stream()
                .map(ClientDto::new)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultExcelGeneratorServiceImpl<ClientDto> exportToExcel() {
        List<ClientDto> list = this.getAll();
        ExcelView excelView = new ExcelView();
        List<ExcelView> views = excelView.viewBuilder();
        return new DefaultExcelGeneratorServiceImpl<>(list, views);
    }
}

public interface ClientService {
    public List<ClientDto> getAll();
    public Page<ClientEntity> getAll(Pageable paging);
    public List<ClientDto> getAllByRegDateAfter();
    DefaultExcelGeneratorServiceImpl<ClientDto> exportToExcel();
}
```

Scheduler

```
@Component
public class SchedulerService {

    private final ClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    public SchedulerService(ClientService clientService) {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void downloadBlockedClients() {
        try {
            List<ClientDto> clientDtos = clientService.getAll().stream().map(ClientDto::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
            String fileName = "select.csv";
            File file = new File(fileName);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

            Writer writer = Channels.newWriter(outputStream.getChannel(), "UTF-8");
            writer.append("id|created_dt|username|name|amount|status|account|external_id|external_status").append("\n");
            for (ClientDto dto : clientDtos) {
                writer.append(dto.toString()).append("\n");
            }
               
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I am making a selection from a database and trying to save this data to a csv file. There are no errors. However, the csv file is kept blank.
Perhaps this is a problem in the methods that I use, or rather in the use of Entity. I can't find the answer.
Plus, created_at must be split into two columns (one for the date and the other for the time).

Comment: You query is native, have you ran it on your database to see if it works and returns results? If yes then try to debug your `SchedulerService`  at `List<ClientDto> clientDtos = clientService.getAll().stream().map(ClientDto::new).collect(Collectors.toList());` and check if this `List<ClientDto>` is not empty. If all the above work correctly then check your `ClientDto#toString()` method if it produces anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must invoke the `close()` method of the `Writer`, otherwise, it won't write
the current buffer on your file.

Add this code at the end of your `try` block:

```
...
writer.close();
...
```

or create a finally block.

Comment: @Аристотель Did as you said, the column names are saved in the file. But the data from the database is not showing ...

Comment: Ok so now we resolve the writing issue. Let's check how you get the data from the db. I will update my answer if I find an issue. One question at your ClientService getAll() method you already collect the result to a List<> why you do it again when you call the service.getAll() at your ScheduledService?

Comment: I'm still newbie) And I called it again because I found the correct code. I guess the problem is around here. But my experience still does not make it clear to me until the end ...

Comment: When querying in sql, everything is displayed correctly. Also the created_dt column in my query is split into two columns - date and time. When forming the csv file, I did not show it. Maybe this is also the problem?

Comment: Can you please check if your retrieved List<ClientDto> is empty or not? Debug your code by adding breakpoints and check if your call returns anything. Start from your ClientService and print the list without mapping it to ClientDto.  See there if you get thre correct responses. And then print when you map it to the ClientDto. Just to check if the mapping is correct

Comment: My base went off, I set it up again. The point is that I am taking data from three tables. Now I get an error that the name column does not exist, since the data from three tables, I am trying to save to a (temporary) table that is not in the database. How can I get out of this situation? Everything works correctly in pgAdmin.

Comment: @Alex I can't help you in the comments, the best thing to do is close this question, once the CSV file writing issue is resolved, and ask a new one about the error you face, otherwise are too many issues together and we will mess up the whole question and lose our focus. This way others can contribute to help as well and solve your issue :)