# o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper: ERROR: Column cliententi0_.name does not exist

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, csv

Repostory

```
@Repository
public interface ClientRepository extends JpaRepository<ClientEntity, Long> {

    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = "SELECT pp.id, TO_CHAR(pp.created_dt::date, 'dd.mm.yyyy')\n" +
               "AS 'Data', CAST(pp.created_dt AS time(0)) AS 'Time', au.username AS 'UserName',\n" +
               "ss.name AS 'Service', pp.amount AS 'Amount',\n" +
               "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success') AS 'Payment_status', pp.account AS 'Account',\n" +
               "pp.external_id AS 'Idn', COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'DN')\n" +
               "AS 'Stat'\n" +
               "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
               "INNER JOIN user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
               "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
               "WHERE pp.created_dt >= '2021-09-28'\n" +
               "AND ss.name = 'Faberlic' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'", nativeQuery = true)
    List<Client> getAllByRegDate();
}
```

Inteface

```
public interface Client {

    Long getId();
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    LocalDate getCreated_dt();
    String getUsername();
    String getName();
    int getAmount();
    String getStatus();
    String getAccount();
    String getExternal_id();
    String getExternal_status();
}
```

DTO

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString

public class ClientDto {
    private Long id;
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING)
    private LocalDate created_dt;
    private String username;
    private String name;
    private int amount;
    private String status;
    private String account;
    private String external_id;
    private String external_status;

    public ClientDto(Client client) {
        this.id = client.getId();
        /...
        /...
        this.external_status = client.getExternal_status();
    }

    public ClientDto(ClientDto clientDto) {
        this.id = clientDto.getId();
        
        /...

        this.external_status = clientDto.getExternal_status();
    }

    public ClientDto(ClientEntity clientEntity) {
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "" + id + "|" + created_dt + "|" + username + "|" + name +
                "|" + amount + "|" + status + "|" + account + "|" + external_id + "|" + external_status;
    }
}
```

Entity

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Immutable
@Entity
@Table(name = "payments", schema = "public")
public class ClientEntity {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "created_dt")
    private LocalDate created_dt;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "amount")
    private int amount;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @Column(name = "account")
    private String account;

    @Column(name = "external_id")
    private String external_id;

    @Column(name = "external_status")
    private String external_status;
}
```

I am trying to save data to a csv file. I take data from one database, from three tables. In entity @Table in "name" I specify one of the existing tables - "payment". All data is taken from three tables (as I have written in Query). But when program is run, an error appears that the "name" column does not exist. This column is in another table from which I am fetching data. Can't figure out what I should do.

Comment: `AS 'UserName'` is invalid SQL - identifiers can not be enclosed in single quotes.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS

Comment: `"ss.name AS 'Service'` which labels the column named `service` not `name` where as your `Client` has a `getName` which requires a `name` result column which your resultset doesn't contain. Either rename `getName` to `getService` or rename the column from `Service` to `Name`.

Comment: @M. Deinum Did as you said. Now writes that the column "service" does not exist. Maybe the point is that I take this column from another table? I take data from three tables and (as I think) some temporary table should be created, which will then be saved to a csv file?

Comment: No you don't need a temporary table. Basically all the getters in your interface need a corresponding column. Apparently your result doesn't contain enough columns (or properly named columns) to satisfy that requirement.

Comment: I also don't get all of your abstractions? A projection, which is turned into a DTO with a toString to write the csv? You already have a query just use a `JdbcTemplate` and a `RowCallback` to write the rows to a csv file. You are making things overly complex with your current structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of an answer to this question and the question you asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431557/when-exporting-from-the-database-an-empty-csv-file-is-created), combined. Imho you are making things overly complex with your structure of having a `Client` interface which is used as a projection, which is then turned into a `ClientDto` (why? the projection is already a DTO) and you have your entities.

Instead of doing this just use a [`JdbcTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html) with a [`RowCallbackHandler`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/RowCallbackHandler.html) to write the rows to CSV. This will use a lot less memory, be faster (as you aren't creating multiple objects per row to then throw it away, and you don't have all the rows in memory).

```java
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class SchedulerService {

    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT pp.id, pp.created_dt au.username, ss.name, pp.amount\n" +
        "REPLACE(pp.status, 'SUCCESS', 'Success'), pp.account,\n" +
        "pp.external_id AS 'Idn', COALESCE(pp.external_status, null, 'DN') AS 'Stat'\n" +
        "FROM payments AS pp\n" +
        "INNER JOIN user AS au ON au.id = pp.creator_id\n" +
        "INNER JOIN services AS ss ON ss.id = pp.service_id\n" +
        "WHERE pp.created_dt >= '2021-09-28'\n" +
        "AND ss.name = 'Faberlic' AND pp.status = 'SUCCESS'";

    private static final DateTimeFormatter date_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
    private static final DateTimeFormatter time_format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");

    private final JdbcTemplate jdbc;

    public SchedulerService(JdbcTemplate jdbc) {
        this.jdbc = jdbc;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void downloadBlockedClients() {
        String filename = "select.csv";

        try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename)) {
            writer.append("id|date|time|username|name|amount|status|account|external_id|external_status").append('\n');
            this.jdbc.query(QUERY, (ResultSet rs) -> writeLine(writer, rs));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void writeLine(FileWriter writer, ResultSet rs) {
        try {
            LocalDateTime ldt = rs.getTimestamp("created_dt").toLocalDateTime();
            writer.append(String.valueOf(rs.getLong("id")));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(ldt.format(date_format));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(ldt.format(time_format));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("username"));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("name"));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(String.valueOf(rs.getBigDecimal("amount")));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("status"));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("account"));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("idn"));
            writer.append('|');
            writer.append(rs.getString("stat"));
            writer.append('\n');
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Something along these lines will make your resources more efficient (saves the copying, having results duplicated in memory) and should be faster. You could move the row handling to a method so your lambda gets a bit more readable.

**NOTE:** I assumed that you are using Spring Boot and that the `JdbcTemplate is available out-of-the-box. If not you need to configure one next to your JPA configuration.

```java
@Bean
public JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate(DataSource dataSource) {
  return new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
}
```

Comment: That is, should I delete dto and interface? And further. In my case, the created_dt column is divided into two columns - date and time. I don’t understand how I can do this either ...

Comment: Have you actually **read** the answer.

Comment: Did as you do.     1.   In this pert:  try (FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(filename, StandardCharsets.UTF_8) - Cannot resolve constructor 'FileWriter(java.lang.String, java.nio.charset.Charset)' 2. Also underlines writer.append, asks to wrap each one in a try / catch block

Comment: I am using java 8, fixed the bugs. Launched the project. Error: SQL state [24000]; error code [0]; ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ResultSet not positioned properly, perhaps you need to call next.

Comment: There is already an enclosing try/catch so you shouldn't need (nor should) wrap all those calls in separate try/catch statements. Looks like there as 1 too many curly branches leading to an eager close of the catch. Regarding the constructor that is available since java11 so yes that doesn't work on Java8, but one with just 1 string should work. I also wonder which Spring version you are using?

Comment: Doh, its a try/catch inside the lambda ofcourse.

Comment: Added an updated (java 8 compatible) version of the code, extracted the lambda to a method for readability.

Comment: I changed as you advised. Now an error like this: java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: status columns not found in this ResultSet.

Comment: If I understood you correctly. In the project, I left only: interface (Client), entity (ClientEntity) and SchedulerService

Comment: Why would you need the `Client` interface? You don't need that, the scheduler service does the export.

Comment: Do everything as you said. I can't understand why the error is that the "status" columns in the ResultSet were not found

Comment: Corrected a few points. Everything worked. Thanks))